# How do I write directly to the screen?

Tags: graphics, x11, window-management

Specifically, I want to display text and images on the monitor, on top of all other windows, but without being clickable or in any way possible to interact with - clicks on it should go straight through to whatever window is underneath.

So far, my research has led me to try and read the X documentation regarding the composite overlay window, but unfortunately I have not been able to get anywhere with it. The only resource I found that was of any help is a small nodejs library (node-x11) which unfortunately appears to have been abandoned while still incomplete, and which I was not able to get to work. Apparently there is also a python library, but that seemed to be even less complete than the nodejs on.

Answer (score 2):

[node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) author here (and it's not abandoned, I just only add functionality I need or users request, so if you missing something please fill an issue!)

You can use `GetOverlayWindow` from [composite extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/compositeproto/compositeproto.txt):

> Version 0.3 of the protocol adds the Composite Overlay Window, which
>   provides compositing managers with a surface on which to draw without
>   interference. This window is always above normal windows and is always
>   below the screen saver window. It is an InputOutput window whose width
>   and height are the screen dimensions. Its visual is the root visual
>   and its border width is zero.  Attempts to redirect it using the
>   composite extension are ignored.  This window does not appear in the
>   reply of the QueryTree request. It is also an override redirect window.
>   These last two features make it invisible to window managers and other X11
>   clients. The only way to access the XID of this window is via the
>   CompositeGetOverlayWindow request. Initially, the Composite Overlay
>   Window is unmapped.
>
> CompositeGetOverlayWindow returns the XID of the Composite Overlay
>   Window. If the window has not yet been mapped, it is mapped by this
>   request. When all clients who have called this request have terminated
>   their X11 connections the window is unmapped.
>
> Composite managers may render directly to the Composite Overlay
>   Window, or they may reparent other windows to be children of this
>   window and render to these. Multiple clients may render to the
>   Composite Overlay Window, create child windows of it, reshape it, and
>   redefine its input region, but the specific arbitration rules followed
>   by these clients is not defined by this specification; these policies
>   should be defined by the clients themselves.

node-x11 example:

```
var x11 = require('x11');
x11.createClient(function(err, display) {
  var X = display.client;
  var root = display.screen[0].root;
  X.require('composite', function(err, Composite) {
    Composite.GetOverlayWindow(root, function(err, overlayId) {
      // now you can draw on overlayId window here.
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I was able to get it to create a new window (with X.CreateWindow) and then draw on it, but I was never able to get it to draw on the overlay window, and after a couple of days work I gave up in frustration - I think I just don't understand nodejs well enough to figure out how it works, and it's at that awkward height where it's too far from the C for the X docs to help, but still too low level to guess at.

Comment: I made it partly work by making a normal window then parenting it to the overlay, but I moved on to PyQt5 in the end